# VS Code detects venv successfully but not accessing packages installed inside

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, pycharm

I recently created a python project using scikit learn on PyCharm. First, I followed the sample code on official website
`from sklearn import linear_model` and moved on to rest of the code.

Then I tried to run it on vscode, I set the interpreter to its venv, same as it was in pycharm, but i got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> from sklearn import linear_model
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

which is weird because i have never seen this erron on pycharm.

any idea what is going wrong?

Steps/Code to Reproduce

just include from sklearn import linear_model in your code, assume you have installed the packages, both vscode and pycharm should compile and you wont see any error at this stage

Expected Results

run whatever the rest of your code is

Actual Results

get an error mentioned above

any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it according to the following steps.

1. Ensure that you have installed package in your venv environment.
2. Use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type `Python: Select Interpreter` to change your python interpreter to venv environment.
3. Run your python file by clicking button **Run Python File** which is provided by Python extension instead of `Run Code` button.
4. If it still doesn't work, try to close all terminal and rerun your file.

Comment: Wow it works now! I swear I must be blind to not check that drop-down. Didn't expect the solution to be such easy! A side question, is it possible to set `Run Code` blinded  with `Run Python File`?

Comment: @Anonymous I‘m sorry, what did you mean `blinded with`? If you mean bind, you can open keyboard shortcuts( **ctrl+k ctrl+s**) then search for `Run Python File` and set it.

Comment: sorry for that typo, that's exactly what I meant, thank you!